# How to hide the items only on mobile with isHidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've set up this simple function that hides the element and reveals it onclick. But I only want it to hide on mobile (and obviously for the button only show on mobile as well). How do I do that here vs. css?

```
state = {
        isLoading: true,
        team: [],
        error: null,
        isHidden: true
      }
    toggleHidden () {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
      })
    }
```

And here is the map function that runs on the team array that outputs this:

```
 <span class="arrow" onClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)}>click</span>
                        {!this.state.isHidden && <p>{s.description}</p>}
```

Comment: Why not just handle it with basic css? put a class on a div that you do not want to show and then a media query to `display: none`

Comment: food for thought - "mobile" can be detected a couple of ways but has traditionally been done so based on screen size.  problem is, lately the screen resolutions have gotten higher (a Galaxy S9 resolution is 1440 x 2960) so, yes do it with [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)